# Masked Text Box Control for .NET 1.1

Tags: winforms, controls, .net-1.1, maskedtextbox

I'm having trouble finding a Masked Text Box control for .NET 1.1 (big surprise right, obsolete technology), and I realize this is a long shot, but does anyone here know of one?

Either source code or just a binary works fine.

For now I'm doing `RegEx` validation when the user presses save...

Answer (score 0):

Google: "C# Masked Text Box"

Hit #5:  [Masked C# TextBox Control](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/edit/maskedcsedit.aspx)  Written November 2001 for .NET 1.0 & .NET 1.1

Comment: This is basically what I'm doing right now, read my original message. I'm looking for an actual **masked** text box, like the ones you find in .NET 2 and above.